# Unable to hard code integer value into vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to self-study about vectors using C++.

As far as i know, vector is much more dynamic and efficient as compared to array.

For my practice, i tried to store values of different datatype into the vector and printing those value from the vector.

So i started off by trying to hard-code some value into different datatype of vector such as integer, string and double.

So after some research i attempted to hard code some integer and double value into the vector as shown below.

```
std::vector<int> stockID = {023}; 

std::vector<double> stockPrice;
stockPrice.push_back("50.50");

std::vector<int> stockChange =  {100}; 

std::vector<int> transactionDate = {151212};
```

However it returns me an error called `conversion of int/double to non-scarlar type`.

However when i attempt to hard code value into a vector string it doesn't seem to have any problem.

```
std::vector<string> stockItem; 
stockItem.push_back("Samsung Phone");

std::vector<string> category;
category.push_back("Electronic");

std::vector<string> subCategory;
subCategory.push_back("Mobile Phone");
```

May i ask how does the string vector works differently from int and double vector to produce such error.

Comment: Anything quoted in `""` is a *string-literal* in C++. Your `stockPrice` only stores `double`, and there is no such implicit conversion from a *string-literal* to `double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by [whiZTiM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621391/whiztim) in comment section of question.

> Anything quoted in `""` is a string-literal in C++. Your `stockPrice` only stores `double`, and there is no such implicit conversion from a string-literal to `double`

If you want to in vector `stockPrice`. It should be like

```
stockPrice.push_back(50.50);
```

Instead of

```
stockPrice.push_back("50.50");
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to invoke a [constructor of `vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), so remove some `=`  sign:

```
std::vector<int> stockID{023};
```

<sup>BTW, `023` is octal notation for 19.</sup>

Of course, `pusk_back` is a member function, so you can only call it (as a *statement*) inside some function body and you need to pass the appropriate type. Obviously, `"50.50"` is a string literal, not a floating point literal. So this should work:

```
void f() {
  std::vector<double> stockPrice;
  stockPrice.push_back(50.50);
}
```

assuming it appears at top-level (not inside the body of another function).

Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info when compiling, e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Be sure to learn at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (not some older version of the standard). Perhaps pass `-std=c++11` if you have some *old* version of `g++`. I recommend (in February 2017) to use some [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) at least.

> I'm trying to self-study about vectors using C++.

Don't study *vectors* but the whole C++ (C++11 or C++14) programming language (which is a difficult and complex programming language). So read  a recent edition of e.g. [*Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) and see also some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site.

Look also inside source code of some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) in C++ (be sure that it is recent and genuine C++11 or better).

BTW, this should work

```
 std::vector<std::string> category{"Electronic","Furniture"};
```

Comment: now it returns me another error called a function-definition is not allowed before the '{' token.

Comment: Did you paste the function into the main function? You cant declare a function inside another function

Comment: yes i have. i input all the hardcoded data into the main function for example, `int main() { std::vector<int> stockID {999};  }`

Comment: @Kerndog73 not all compilers support {} without =. Certainly I can't do that in VS..it was a late addition to draft. The error message sounds literally what  big&hard compiler answers on that.